# SharePoint List to Access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to remove HTML Tags when export SharePoint 2013 list to Access 2013?
When i Open SharePoint list in Access in a form designed with Info-path how can i remove the HTML tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your fields to Plain Text in InfoPath or SP. Dont use Rich Text Format.

Answer (score -1):

Function Response: PlainText([ResponseText])     Field Name: PlainText([Fieldname that includes html tags])